# How to plot this 3D graph from excel using matplotlib

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have attached a graph:
[This is a graph from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzpEf.png)

I want to create the same graph using code in matplotlib. I checked online for 3d graphs but didn't get anything similar to this.

[This is the data that needs to be plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSUsK.png)
In the above picture, Data1, Data2, Data3 must be in the x-axis.
V1, V2, V3 in the z-axis and the values in the y-axis

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

We have to use Axes3D and art3d modules.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, art3d

# Extract data from Excel file or spreadsheet
x, y, z, colors = ...

# Create pyramid objects
pyramids = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    pyramid = art3d.Pyramid()
    pyramid.set_verts([(x[i], y[i], z[i]),
                  (x[i] + 0.5, y[i], z[i]),
                  (x[i], y[i] + 0.5, z[i]),
                  (x[i] - 0.5, y[i], z[i]),
                  (x[i], y[i], z[i] + 1)])
    pyramid.set_color(colors[i])
    pyramids.append(pyramid)

# Create plot and customize
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Add pyramids to plot
for pyramid in pyramids:
    ax.add_artist(pyramid)

# Set labels, title, and adjust view
ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Axis')
plt.title('3D Scatter Plot of Pyramids')
ax.view_init(elev=15, azim=-60)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why do you have two answers? Just edit your old answer or delete it.

Comment: @MB-44 Tried executing the code and I get an error - "AttributeError: module 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d' has no attribute 'Pyramid'"

Comment: okay, wait! I'll find a solution